# How to mock Forge Viewer in React Unit Tests

Tags: autodesk-forge

we're currently trying to unit / integration test our react application, which uses the forge viewer cdn script.

the to be tested code assumes that `Autodesk` is available on the window object, which is the case in the application (via `script` tags), but not in the context of testing. this leads to errors like these:

```
Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: Autodesk is not defined
    > 1 | export class ExtendedGuiViewer3D extends Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D {
```

according to the license comments, the forge viewer script only allows using it through the Autodesk servers, so I cant just download it, and `require` the file locally.

has anyone successfully tested components that use the forge viewer scripts?

Comment: I am not good at React, just finding some blogs about using Forge Viewer with React. are they helpful to you? This blog collects all blogs related with React https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/react-typescript-showing-shared-model

Answer (score 1):

#### Intro

Disclaimer, I've only recently been experimenting with "Reactifying" the `Autodesk Forge Viewer`!

I currently believe the 'correct' way to consume the forge viewer `css` / `js` is to pull code from the Autodesk hosted `cdn`. The types are still available on `npm` though.

For example, the endpoints for `v7.52.0`:

- js `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.52.0/viewer3D.min.js`
- css `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.52.0/style.min.css`

#### Steps

##### 1. Add type information from npm

Firstly, if you are using typescript, you can still install the viewer types from `npm` with:

`yarn add -D @types/forge-viewer` (check/add specific version to match the version of the script from the `cdn` - you can verify in your `package.json`)

##### 2. Sample `ViewingContext.tsx`

In your React code you may wish to create a React Context to manage the the script downloading for you. This example is based on `next.js`:

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Script from "next/script";

export const ViewingContext = React.createContext({
  initialized: false,
});

export interface ViewingContextProps {
  options: Autodesk.Viewing.InitializerOptions;
}

// Place a single global ViewingContextProvider component around the common root of all your Autodesk.Viewing (LMV) components.
// https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/
export const ViewingContextProvider = ({
  options,
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<ViewingContextProps>): JSX.Element => {
  const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(
    typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      window.Autodesk?.Viewing?.Initializer !== undefined
  );
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scriptLoaded && !initialized) {
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => setInitialized(true));
    }
  }, [options, initialized, scriptLoaded]);

  return (
    <ViewingContext.Provider value={{ initialized }}>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.52.0/style.min.css"
        type="text/css"
      />
      <Script
        async
        src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.52.0/viewer3D.min.js"
        onLoad={(): void => setScriptLoaded(true)}
      />
      {children}
    </ViewingContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

##### 3. Sample `Viewer.tsx` Component

Only mount this component as a child of the `ViewingContext`. You can also modify/replace this component with the `ExtendedGuiViewer3D` you mentioned.

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { ViewingContext } from "./ViewingContext";

export interface ViewerProps {
  config?: Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3DConfig;
  onLoaded?: (viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D) => void;
  onError?: (code: number) => void;
}

// Thin wrapper around https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/
// Add your own imperative hook code after GuiViewer object is loaded with the onLoaded callback.
// Place inside a relative layout div.
export const Viewer = ({
  config,
  onLoaded,
  onError,
}: ViewerProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { initialized: viewingContextInitialized } = useContext(ViewingContext);
  const viewerDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const viewer = useRef<Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D>();

  // Viewer imperative loading code
  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewingContextInitialized && !viewer.current && viewerDivRef.current) {
      viewer.current = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
        viewerDivRef.current,
        config
      );
      const startedCode = viewer.current.start();
      if (startedCode > 0) {
        onError && onError(startedCode);
        return;
      }
      if (onLoaded) onLoaded(viewer.current);
    }
  }, [config, onLoaded, onError, viewingContextInitialized]);

  // Viewer destructor
  useEffect(() => {
    return (): void => {
      if (viewer.current) {
        viewer.current.finish();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        overflow: "hidden",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          margin: 0,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
        ref={viewerDivRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: thank you but I did not ask about how to implement the forge viewer in react. we already do that just fine. i'm specifically asking about how to handle it for component **tests**.

Comment: Hey @AlexSpieslechner, ah sorry yes, your main question was related to testing. I think due to the nature of the Viewer depending heavily on the window object and the canvas webgl context (three.js based), your best solution for testing will be to look at e2e testing that use a full browser such as Cypress (https://www.cypress.io/).

Comment: thats unfortunately also not my question. my question is only about fixing the missing `Autodesk` global, so that unit / integration tests for components can run properly.

we're not trying to test the forge viewer itself.

Comment: If that helps, I'm sure that for testing purposes it's ok to download the Viewer JavaScript file - but you should not provide it from your own server in your final, live product

Comment: @AdamNagy oh thats great to hear, thank you. I've been trying to mock out the custom Autodesk and THREE namespaces in jest, and it was a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

so after months of fighting, these are the two options I've come up with so far.

## option 1: dirty mock everything

there's a few `@ts-ignore`, because I dont want to mock out the whole package. i'll only mock the parts my application uses.

> you could to type assertion like `global.THREE = {...} as unknown as typeof THREE` too. whatever floats your boat.

```
// setupTests.ts

// NOP_VIEWER global is not part of the @types declaration, so we need to tell typescript that there will be a global
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      NOP_VIEWER: ExtendedGuiViewer3DTypes;
    }
  }
}

global.Autodesk = {
  // @ts-ignore
  Viewing: {
    GuiViewer3D: jest.fn(),
    Extension: jest.fn(),
    ToolInterface: jest.fn(),
  },
};

// @ts-ignore
global.THREE = {
  Color: jest.fn(),
  Vector4: jest.fn(),
};

global.NOP_VIEWER = {
  disableSelection: jest.fn(),
  resize: jest.fn(),
  // @ts-ignore
  model: {
    getExternalIdMapping: (successCallback: any, _: any) => {
      successCallback({ 'test-guid': 1 });
    },
  },
  clearThemingColors: jest.fn(),
  setThemingColor: jest.fn(),
  isLoadDone: () => true,
  isolate: jest.fn(),
};
```

## option 2: download and require

> As Autodesk Developer Adam Nagy pointed out, you probably wont get sent to jail, if you download the script file and require it locally for your tests only. (note that this is just a "probably")

keep in mind that even if you require the file, you still have to mock `NOP_VIEWER` as this global is only available after initializing the viewer (which you dont want to do in your tests)

```
// setupTests.ts

// replace the mocks of `Autodesk` and `THREE` with this require.

require('./vendors/Autodesk/viewer3D.min');
```

in my tests i can then use the `jest` spies on `NOP_VIEWER`

```
expect(NOP_VIEWER.clearThemingColors).toHaveBeenCalled();
```